# When would you return a reference from a function?

Tags: c++, function, reference

I don't understand when I would ever want to return a reference from a function (i.e. `T& func(){...}`).

For example:

```
T& func() {
    Something t;
    return t;
}
```

This creates a `Something` instance named `t`, and then returns it by reference. When we go out of scope, `t` is lost. So the reference is referring to `0` I think..?

So in other words, why would I ever want to return either a reference or a const reference? Please explain and give examples.

Comment: Its not uncommon to return a reference to a static variable defined in a function. Also member functions often return references. Whenever the reference is to an object that lasts longer than the function if could make sense.

Comment: Another example is max. Pay careful attention to the return type in the sample implementation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/

Comment: How would the reference magically start referring to `0`? What does that even mean?

Comment: See: [Move semantics in C++ 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics) - usually a better away to go.

Comment: The object would go out of scope, and the pointer would be a dangling pointer (dangling reference?). But dangling pointers don't magically get assigned to nullptr, and there are no null references even if they did.

Comment: But that's only if you're returning a reference to a local. You might be returning a reference or const reference to a data member of a class, which will stay in scope as long as the object does. Or a reference to a global / static global. Or you might even return one of your parameters, (such is common with operator<< and operator>>).

Answer (score 3):

You often do it when you are returning a member from one of the function's arguments. An example from the standard library:

```
template<class T, size_t n>
struct array
{
    T data[n];

    T& operator[](size_t i) { return data[i]; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you return a reference to a static variable defined in a function:

```
T& func() {
    static Something t; // this will exist until program closes
    return t;
}
```

That's a technique to help combat problems involving the order of static initialization.

Obviously member variables can make sense (I'm sure you're not asking about those though):

```
T& MyType::func() {
    return this->t; // persists with the object
}
```

Also sometimes you want to return the object that was passed in to the function:

```
std::ostream& operaor<<(std::ostream& os, const MyType& t) {
    // blah blah
    return os; // pass it back out
}
```

That enables you to chain functions together like:

```
if(std::getline(input >> size >> std::ws, line))
{
    // size and line were successfully read here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of references as little more than pointers. Any time you'd return a pointer from a function, you might return a reference type instead.

I think your issue with returning references is the issue of scope. As long as there are no scope issues, it's just another tool at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a reference to the current object is used for implementing a user-defined assignment operator.

```
class Foo
{
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&);
  //...
};
```

It is also used as a return type when implementing overloads of operators `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, etc.  These operators suggest that the return type is the adjusted current object, not a new object.  Therefore to return the current object, you return a reference to `*this`.